# I cannot send a message from my client using websocket to local server

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I'm working on webstorm exactly a PhoneGap project and websocket  and I cannot send a message from my client using websocket to local server. Thank you for your help.

```html
<!--
  Lincense: Public Domain
-->

<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Sample of web_socket.js</title>
  <script src="js/websocket.js"></script>
  <!-- Include these three JS files: -->



  <script type="text/javascript">
    function WebSocketTest()
    {
      if ("WebSocket" in window)
      {
        alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");

        // Let us open a web socket
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9777");

        ws.onopen = function()
        {
          // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
          ws.send("message");
          alert("Message is sent...");
        };

        ws.onmessage = function (evt)
        {

          alert("Message is received...");
        };

        ws.onclose = function()
        {
          // websocket is closed.
          alert("Connection is closed...");
        };
      }

      else
      {
        // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
        alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
      }
    }
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="sse">
  <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
</div>

</body></html>
```

I have been working on this problem for 2 days any help please!